# Problema con template de django! No renderiza valor de un diccionario

Tags: django, django-templates

esta es mi primera pregunta y les agradezco de antemano!
Estoy trabajando con una app de django (MVT). Tengo una vista que retorna un diccionario y me gustaria acceder a elementos sueltos del diccionario en un template. Pero sucede que en el template puedo renderizar sin problemas el diccionario completo pero elementos sueltos no.
Les muestro la vista con la funcion que importa al final

```
class GrillaView(View):
    template_name = 'grilla.html'

    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, self.template_name)

    def contar_registros(self, fecha):
       ... 

    def post(self, request, fecha=None):
        if fecha:
        ...
        else:
            # Esta parte se ejecutará cuando se envíe el formulario del mes y año
            mes = int(request.POST.get('mes'))
            ano = int(request.POST.get('ano'))
            
            dias_en_mes = [dia for dia in range(1, monthrange(ano, mes)[1] + 1)]
            registros_por_dia = {}

            for dia in dias_en_mes:
                fecha = datetime(ano, mes, dia).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                contador = self.contar_registros(fecha)
                registros_por_dia[dia] = contador
         
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'dias_en_mes': dias_en_mes, 'registros_por_dia': registros_por_dia})
```

Y a continuacion les muestro la parte en cuestión del template

```
...
{% if dias_en_mes %}
    {% with fecha_format='%Y-%m-%d' %}
    <div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">

        {% for dia in dias_en_mes %}
        {% with fecha=dia|date:fecha_format %}
        <div style="width: 50px; height: 50px; border: 1px solid black; margin: 5px;">
            <span>{{ dia }}</span>
            <br>
            <span>{{registros_por_dia.dia}}</span>
            
        </div>
        {% endwith %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {% endwith %}
    {% endif %}
    {% endblock %}
```

La linea de `<span>{{registros_por_dia.dia}}</span>` no renderiza ningun valor. Pero si la cambio por `<span>{{registros_por_dia}}</span>` ahi si me renderiza el diccionario completo. He probado con un monton de variantes

- `<span>{{registros_por_dia|get:dia}}</span>`
- `<span>{{registros_por_dia.get(dia, 'Valor predeterminado')}}</span>`
- `{% with registro=registros_por_dia.dia %}<span>{{ registro }}</span>              {% endwith %}`
- `<span>{{registros_por_dia|getattr:dia}}</span>`
- `<span>{{registros_por_dia[dia]}}</span>`
- `<span>{{registros_por_dia|dictlookup:dia}}</span>`

Ninguno funciona, alguien sabe que puedo hacer?
Muchas gracias!!